# Question about set of isomorphism class of principal G-bundle

Tags: algebraic-topology

Previously, I asked about [a question what is classifying space BG](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4508241/question-about-weakly-contractible-space-with-free-g-action-eg?noredirect=1#comment9464523_4508241)?(More precisely, my main question is how to define $EG$ explicitly. I found an answer myself about the question. According to the 17page(based on the PDF) [following lecture](http://www.math.iupui.edu/%7Edramras/601/lectures3-5.pdf) , It seems just a notation or terminology.

[image]

Nevertheless, I am still stuck ; I don't understand how to define $\operatorname{Prin}_G(X)$ explicitly. This is called an **isomorphism class** (of principal G-bundle). The author on the lecture describes

$$\operatorname{Prin}_G(X):=\left\{ \operatorname{principal~G-bundle} \right\}/\simeq$$

To begin with, Let $G$ be a topological group. Then,

- a **left $G$-space** is a space $X$ equipped with a continuous map left $G$-action.
- Let $X$ and $Y$ be a $G$-space. Then, a **$G$-equivariant map** or **$G$-map** (or, more shortly an **equivariant map**) is a map $\sigma : X \to Y$ such that $\sigma(gx)=g\sigma(x)$ for all $g\in G, x\in X$.
- Let $B$ a topological space and suppose that $P$ is a right $G$-bundle equipped with a $G$-map $\pi : P \to B$ where $G$ acts on $B$.  Then we call $(P,\pi,B)$ is a **principal bundle** if $\pi$ satisfies the local triviality condition.

Next,here is the definition of a morphism of principal bundle:

A **morphism of principal bundle** over B is an equivariant map $\sigma : P \to Q$ ... and the set of **isomorphism class** of principal $G$-bundle over $B$ will denote $\mathcal{P}_G B$.

(**Note**. all definitions I mentioned are obtained from [here](https://math.mit.edu/%7Embehrens/18.906spring10/prin.pdf), and $\mathcal{P}_G B$ means $\operatorname{prin}_G(X)$. I will use $\operatorname{prin}_G(X)$ throughout my question.  )

my question : What on earth *isomorphism class*?

- **isomorphism** : To begin with, when considering the definition of $G$-map, both objects $P$ and $Q$ are arbitrary sets, but not a group in general. Thus, I think that *group isomorphism* does not make sense and [isomorphism in the sense of category](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isomorphism_of_categories#:%7E:text=In%20category%20theory%2C%20two%20categories,one%20correspondence%20to%20each%20other.) would make sense. Is it right?

**Edit**: I misunderstood the term "$G$-*equivariant* map " as ""$G$-*equivalent* map" Also, according to the comment, I realized that the isomorphism means a bundle isomorphism.

Then, is an **isomorphism class** an equivalent class between isomorphism of principal bundle? (the relation between two (bundle) isomorphism maps  satisfies an equivalence relation and it would makes sense that its class is called isomorphism class.)

Comment: Isomorphism, in the sense of _bundles_; and probably you meant "equivariant map" instead of "equivalent map".

Comment: It sounds as if you're effectively asking for an introductory short course about bundles, group actions, principal bundles, classifying maps, and all that, which is not really a good fit for this site. Do you have access to a university library, where you can find reliable book references on this material?

Comment: @JHF : I distorted the terminology.  I misunderstood the term $G$-*equivariant* map as $G$-*equivalent* map.  I corrected my wrong typing.

Comment: @AndrewD.Hwang , this is so personal story, I am not a student now, ( but just will have a plan for studying  as a graduate student in the future.)